# What is the purpose of gates with more than 2 inputs?

Tags: quantum-gate, universal-gates

What is the purpose of multi-qubit gates (n>=3), if gates with one or two inputs are enough for any computation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very similar to the same question for classical computation. You can express all algorithms that can be described with Boolean logic using only NOR or NAND logical gates, but you really don't want to do that manually when you're reasoning about functions with thousands of inputs. Instead, you want to use some convenient high-level representation to express your algorithms, and trust your compiler to break it down to the primitive logical gates.

The same holds for quantum computation: when you implement an algorithm that acts on hundreds or thousands of qubits, you really don't want to have to spell it out in single- and two-qubit gates! Multi-qubit gates allow you to express such algorithms concisely, and to focus on the logic of the algorithm rather than on the gate synthesis that can be done automatically by the compiler.

Comment: Good answer. It's also worth nothing that directly engineering a richer basis set (such as provided by multi-qubit gates) can enable _simpler_ compilations, reducing run-time complexity and error accumulation.